# how can i get the values of some inputs from database after select option in dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, laravel

I'm building an HTML form that contains all information about clients, and the others information, so I would when I choose the name of the client that is in the dropdown (select options that contain all name of clients ) the other input fields like (address, tel, email) should be filled automatically.

I don't know what I have to use ajax or jquery and how to use it.

this is my view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Création de commandes</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form id="form2" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{url('gestion_commandes/create')}}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('nomp') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="nomp" class="col-md-1 control-label">Client</label>

                            <div class="col-md-5">

                                     <select name="nomclient" id="nomclient"  class="form-control dynamic" data-dependent="organisme" required autofocus>
                                          <option>--Select--</option>
                                          @foreach ($clientscombos as $clientcombos)
                                          <option value="{{$clientcombos->nom}}">{{$clientcombos->nom}} </option>
                                          @endforeach
                                     </select>

                         </div>
                         {{ csrf_field() }}

                             <label for="organisme" class="col-md-1 control-label">Organisme</label>

                          <div class="col-md-5">
                                <input id="organisme" type="text" class="form-control" name="organisme" value="{{$clientcombos->organisme}}"  required  autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('organisme'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('organisme') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>




                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('adresse') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

                            <label for="adresse" class="col-md-1 control-label">Adresse</label>

                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <input id="adresse" type="text" class="form-control" name="adresse" value="{{$clientcombos->adresse}}"   autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('adresse'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('adresse') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <label for="emailp" class="col-md-1 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <input id="emailp" type="email" class="form-control" name="emailp" placeholder="Saisir l'adresse email" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('emailp'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('emailp') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>




                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('adressep') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

                          <label for="tel" class="col-md-1 control-label">Tel</label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="tel" type="Tel" class="form-control" name="tel"  value="{{$clientcombos->tel1}}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('tel'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('tel') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <label for="tel2p" class="col-md-1 control-label">Tel2</label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="tel2p" type="Tel" class="form-control" name="tel2p"  value="+2126" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('tel2p'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('tel2p') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                         <label for="faxp" class="col-md-1 control-label">Fax</label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                           <input id="faxp" type="Tel" class="form-control" name="faxp" value="{{$clientcombos->fax}}" required autofocus>

                               @if ($errors->has('faxp'))
                              <span class="help-block">
                              <strong>{{ $errors->first('faxp') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                               @endif
                            </div>


                      </div>


















                            <div class=" panel panel-success">                             </div>
                            <div class=" panel panel-success">                             </div>


                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('daterecep') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

                                <label for="commercial" class="col-md-1 control-label">Commercial</label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                            <select name="commercial" id="commercial"  class="form-control" required autofocus>
                                          <option>--Select--</option>
                                          @foreach ($combocommerciaux as $combocommercial)
                                          <option value="{{$combocommercial->name}}">{{$combocommercial->name}} </option>
                                          @endforeach
                                     </select>

                            </div>

                            <label for="datereception" class="col-md-1 control-label">Date de réception</label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="datereception" type="date" class="form-control" name="datereception" placeholder="Saisir le nom complet"  required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('datereception'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('datereception') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <label for="dateprelev" class="col-md-1 control-label">Date de prélevement</label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="dateprelev" type="date" class="form-control" name="dateprelev" placeholder="Saisir le nom complet"  required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('dateprelev'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('dateprelev') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>


                     </div>


                      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('commercial') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                             <label for="savedby" class="col-md-9 control-label">Enregistrée par </label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="savedby" type="text" class="form-control" name="savedby" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('savedby'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('savedby') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('nbrrowsol') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="nbrrowsow" class="col-md-1 control-label">Sol </label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="nbrrowsol" type="number" class="form-control" name="nbrrowsol"  required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('nbrrowsol'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nbrrowsol') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>


                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('nbrroweau') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="nbrroweau" class="col-md-1 control-label">Eau </label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="nbrroweau" type="number" class="form-control" name="nbrroweau"  required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('nbrroweau'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nbrroweau') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('nbrrowveg') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="nbrrowveg" class="col-md-1 control-label">VEG </label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="nbrrowveg" type="number" class="form-control" name="nbrrowveg"  required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('nbrrowveg'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nbrrowveg') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('nbrrowbiof') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="nbrrowbiof" class="col-md-1 control-label">Fertilisant </label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="nbrrowbiof" type="number" class="form-control" name="nbrrowbiof" placeholder="Saisir l'adresse email" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('nbrrowbiof'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nbrrowbiof') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6 control-label">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='{{url('gestion_regions/create')}}'" >Executer</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('nbrrowmicair') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="nbrrowmicair" class="col-md-1 control-label">Mic Air </label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="nbrrowmicair" type="number" class="form-control" name="nbrrowmicair"  required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('nbrrowmicair'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nbrrowmicair') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('nbrrowmiceau') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="nbrrowmiceau" class="col-md-1 control-label">Mic Eau</label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="nbrrowmiceau" type="number" class="form-control" name="nbrrowmiceau"  required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('nbrrowmiceau'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nbrrowmiceau') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('nbrrowmicsurface') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="nbrrowmicsurface" class="col-md-1 control-label">Mic Surface </label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="nbrrowmicsurface" type="number" class="form-control" name="nbrrowmicsurface" placeholder="Saisir l'adresse email" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('nbrrowmicsurface'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nbrrowmicsurface') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>


                      </div>



                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                                    Enregistrer
                                </button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>




            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

this is controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Client;

class DynamicDependent extends Controller
{

    public function comboboxclients()
    {
        $clientscombos = DB::select('select * from clients');
        $combocommerciaux = DB::select('select * from commercials');


        return view('gestion_commandes.create',['clientscombos' => $clientscombos , 'combocommerciaux' => $combocommerciaux]);

    }
}
```

Comment: does the view already have all of the information regarding the clients within the client combos variable?

Comment: yes it has all the information

Comment: if you have the array you dont need to do a ajax request or do anything server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:

1) Server-side: create another action which will fetch client data based on value from select(I suggest you using an client id as select value inside your template).

2) Client-side: add hook on select value change('change' event inside JS), which will send an AJAX request(containing selected value) to action created on step 1, and populate form inputs with received data.

That's pretty much it. Fell free to ask about specific implementation details, but keep in mind that no one will write code for you here, you have to do it yourself, but you'll be fine with this directions.

Comment: thank you, thats what i need, the directions to do it by myself not to have resolution